# InDesign Table of Contents with section headers which occur multiple times

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am currently working on a magazine using Adobe InDesign CS6. On each page I have a head with the name of the section in it, and applied the paragraph style "Header" to the text element. Naturally some of my sections are more than one page long, and because of this, the same header will occur multiple times.

Example of a spread where the header occurs twice:

[image: Example of a spread where the header occurs twice]

Resulting ToC:

[image: Resulting ToC]

My problem is, though, that the header will also occur multiple times in the TOC. Is there a way to skip headers which are similar to the previous one?

Not running headers, because I do not use the header on the page itself. Instead I have subheaders.

Comment: Are you manually typing the "Farve" headers in? If so, I'd look into [InDesign running headers](http://vector.tutsplus.com/tutorials/designing/quick-tip-how-to-make-running-headers-in-adobe-indesign/)

Comment: Yes, text frames on the master and then CTRL + Shift + Click to type in the header. I looked at running headers and thought it was something different from what I wanted. I'll give it another look :)

Comment: @user568458 This was not what I was thinking of. I want the headers on top, but they should not grab the title from the content. I want the Table of Contents on the first page to only include each header once, but if I use the same header on 2 consecutive pages, the header will also appear twice in the table of contents. (Note that the other headers are only used on a single page, not a spread like "Farve" in the example)

Comment: @horatio I was also thinking of the override workaround a few minutes ago while I was walking the dog, should work fine. I will not reorder the pages within a section anyways, so I won't need that constraint for this assignment. You may be right that the running headers are the correct way to do it, I agree, but since most of the "sections" are a single page and only a few of them span over multiple pages I don't think an additional header would add to the design. You should add the workaround along with the correct solution as an answer so I can mark the question as answered :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the correct way is to set up running headers based upon a text, and also set that text to a "TOC-Header" style and then key the TOC off of that style.

An alternative might be to create the TOC-Header style, allow override of the master page item, and then override the paragraph style of the first instance of the header with the TOC-Header style.

This will manually flag it as the TOC item. The drawback is that it will break and require manual intervention if you reorder pages within the section at any point after setting the TOC.

The running header solution allows the content to dictate.

Comment: Thanks, I decided to go with the running headers after all, I suppose I could just as well learn how to do this correctly :)